# Creating new variable based on data in dataframe, ignore NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like that below and want to create a new variable that is a `1/0` or `True/False` if all of the available scores in certain columns are equal to or above 4.

The data is quite messy. Some cells are `NaN` (respondent didn't provide a response), some are white space (bad formatting or respondent pressed space bar, maybe?).

```
ID      Var1 Var2 Var3
id0001  2    NaN  2
id0002  10   3    10
id0003       8    0
id0004  NaN  NaN  NaN
id0005  7    3    7
id0006  NaN  9    9
```

I don't want to drop those rows with a missing value because most have a missing value. I can't just make NaN and white space cells 0 because 0 means something here. I can easily make all white space cells NaN, but I don't know how to ignore them as then I have instances of 'str' and 'int' when I do something like the following:

```
scoreoffouroraboveforall = [(df.Var1 >= 4) & (df.Var2 >= 4) & (df.Var3 >= 4)]
```

This is probably very simple to do, but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with optional parameter `errors=coerce` to convert each of the column in `Var1`, `Var2` and `Var3` to numeric type, then using [`DataFrame.ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) along `axis=1` to create the boolean mask as required with `True/False` values:

```
m = df[['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3']].apply(
    pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').ge(4).all(axis=1)
```

Result:

```
print(m)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: @KJGarbutt Does this answered your question?